# Xamarin Assembly Reference errors

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin, auth0

I have two components that has similar assemblies in that package.

For example: Auth0 SDK and Azure Mobile Services.

Both of these include `Newtonsoft.Json` assembly.

If I add a reference to Auth0, it will show an error in Azure mobile services that some components are not referenced to the project.

If I add a reference also in azure mobile service, it will remove the reference in Auth0.

How to get rid of this error?

[image]

Comment: please choose [Xamarin Component](https://components.xamarin.com) . reference will ad both ways are nuget package adding method and component method .